# Meaning of four/five digit/letter codes on passport stamps

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps

There are 4 or 5 letter/digit codes on e.g. US passport stamp (here 1943):

[image: US]

and Canada passport stamp (here 50174):

[image: Canada]

and Australia passport stamp (here 098U):

[image: Australia]

What is the meaning of these codes?

Comment: Usually, the serial number of the stamp or the number of the agent it is assigned to.

Comment: Or agents pick a stamp at random on each shift, and then stamp a log to record which stamp they used that day

Answer (score 16):

It's a control number identifying the stamp for the purposes of detecting and deterring forgery as well as to identify the officer who placed the stamp in the document should that prove necessary.

As an example, here is an excerpt from the Schengen [Practical Handbook for Border Guards (PDF)](http://register.consilium.europa.eu/doc/srv?l=EN&f=ST%2015010%202006%20INIT) (emphasis added):

> 4.7 Different types of stamps are used to furnish proof of entry and exit (a rectangular stamp
> for entry, a rectangular  stamp  with  rounded  corners  for  exit). These  stamps  contain  the
> letter(s) designating the country as well as indicating the border post, date, **check number**
> and a pictogram indicating the mode of travel used upon entry and exit (overland, by air or
> by sea).
>
> Queries  about  entry  and  exit  stamps,  as  well  as  documentation  relating  to  forged,
> counterfeit, lost or incorrectly affixed stamps, can be asked to the contact point established
> by each Schengen State for this purpose.
>
> 4.8  Each border crossing point **must keep record of the entry and exit stamps handed over to
> and  returned  by  each  border  guard**  carrying  out  the  checks.  This  will  also  include **the
> reference of each respective stamp, which may need to be used for comparative purposes at a later date.**
>
> When the stamps are not used, they must be locked and access to them must be limited to
> the authorised border guards.
>
> 4.9  The **security codes on the stamps** must be changed at regular intervals not exceeding one
> month.